# tkinter .pack(anchor="s") function doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

First it shows the users a couple of check boxes asking the user where they
want to place it on their screen.

These options are as follow: north east, north west, south east and south west then it takes it to another function which (I tested to see if when ticked the correct vars result a 1 and not 0 so vars2 (north west), vars3 (north east), vars4 (south east) and vars5 (south west) all worked and made wheres into nw, ne, se, sw and then finally it displays it on the screen in the position stated by the user.

I tested it a couple of times and all the north east/west seemed to work but when it came to south east/west it appeared in the same spot as north east/west and not like expected. I tried both .grid() and .pack() and it resulted in the same results.

```
def shoall(vars2, vars3, vars4, vars5):
    global g
    global askwhere
    nw = vars2.get()
    ne = vars3.get()
    se = vars4.get()
    sw = vars5.get()
    total = sw+se+nw+ne
    if total >1 or total ==0:
        error.showerror("One","Please select one")
    else:
        g+=1
        if nw ==1:
            wheres = "nw"
            askwhere.destroy()
            allsa(wheres)
        if ne ==1:
            wheres = "ne"
            askwhere.destroy()
            allsa(wheres)
        if se ==1:
            wheres = "se"
            askwhere.destroy()
            allsa(wheres)
        if sw==1:
            wheres="sw"
            askwhere.destroy()
            allsa(wheres)
```

So Like Bryan Oakley mentioned:
I changed the whole code to use `side = "top"`  and `anchor = "n"`  which fixed the issue

Comment: could it be that Lebal is too big as its 6 lines long? so it reverts the anchor? when wheres is S it anchors it to N, SE anchors to NE and SW anchors it to NW

Comment: Are you aware that by default `pack` will place things at the top of the empty space? Also, please create a proper [mcve]?

Comment: I am aware of pack placing things on top but I tried grid as well with same results and I will remember the minimal reproducible example for next time as I didnt know about it.

Comment: Don't just do it for next time. You can [edit] your question to include a better example.

Comment: Is this alright and sorry for that .

Comment: This example is too big and doesn't meet the criteria of a [mcve].

Comment: cannot make it smaller as this explains it all and where I got wheres from and if it was smaller then no one would know where I got some values from.

Comment: We don't really care where the values come from. For the purposes of an example, you can hard-code most of the data. `pack` doesn't care if you computed the anchor or hard-coded it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pack` works by allocating space along one side of the empty space in the master. The `side` option takes one of "top", "bottom", "left", or "right". The default is "top". Thus, if you don't specifiy a side, the widget will be placed at the very top of the empty space.

By default, the allocated space will be just big enough to fit the widget. If the side is "top" or "bottom", the allocated space will be only tall enough to fit the widget, and if the side is "left" or "right" the allocated space will only be wide enough to fit the widget.

The `anchor` option specifies where the widget lies *within the space allocated to it*. Thus, if you only specify `anchor="s"` without specifying the side or any other options, the widget will appear at the top of the available space in the widget and the `anchor` of "s" (south) will seem to have no effect since the space is just tall enough to fit the widget.

[image: screenshot of anchor='s']

If you want the widget to be at the bottom, you can use `side="bottom"`:

[image: screenshot of side='top']

If you want the widget to be at the bottom left, you need to use `anchor='w'` (west) or `anchor='sw'` (southwest) in conjunction with setting the `side` to "bottom".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use anchor while defining label

```
Lebal = Label(login, text=alla, anchor=wheres)
```

you can specify east-west position

south will work only if label is large enough

Comment: It anchors to default position now but not where I want it to and also I want to do Lebal.pack_forget() afterwords to get rid of it so I need to use .pack()

Comment: @Bond007 you can call `pack()` later in the code, it wont be a problem

Comment: @Bond007 both `grid` and `place` are able to "forget". In fact, if you're going to be hiding and showing widgets, `grid` is the better choice because it can remember where a widget was originally placed.

Comment: I am aware of that and tried both of them and both seen to anchor/stick to the north only

Comment: The `anchor` option for the label defines where the text in the label appears, not where the label appears in the window.

Comment: So you said:

south will work only if label is large enough which is the problem I have but how large does the label have to be to make it work??

Comment: @Bryan Oakley does anchor do that but what would you recommend to make it show in the south and why did the label appear at north east, north and north west of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

try changing the last line to

```
Lebal.pack(anchor=s)
```

so basically not wheres, but just s

Comment: yes but wheres is defined by the user so the example would be s

Comment: made wheres "s" as it doesn't work but also your example anchors to N not S like stated to tkinter

Comment: `S` is a tkinter variable and not a string like `wheres`. I think something like small 's' should work, not sure

Comment: Still anchors it to N